# Is the kernel of the adjoint operator equal to the kernel of the operator ($\ker (A)=\ker (A')$)?

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

I am in a middle of a proof where I asked myself about the following:

Is the kernel of the adjoint operator equal to the kernel of the operator ($\ker (A)=\ker (A')$)?

> **Theorem**:Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $A$ an linear bounded operator. The closure of the image is $\overline{Im\: }A=\{y\in Y:f(y)=0,\forall f\in Y'$ such that $A'f=0$}. *$(A'f)(x)=f(A(x))$* is the adjoint operator.

$Im(A)=\ker(A')^\bot$

So I think that is straightforward the following identity:

$\ker (A)=Im(A)^\bot=\ker(A')$

So $\ker (A)=\ker (A')$

**Question:**

Are these moves valid? Is the kernel of the adjoint operator equal to the kernel of the operator ($\ker (A)=\ker (A')$)?

Comment: The kernel of $A'$ lives in $Y'$, and that of $A$ in $X$. They are not subsets of the same set to begin with.

Comment: $A$ and $A'$ have different domains, so how can their kernels be equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $X=X'=Y=Y'$, it is not true that $\ker A'=\ker A$. For instance take $X=\mathbb C^2$, and 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then under the usual identifications one has 
$$
A'=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
In this setting, the equality that holds is that 
$$
\ker A=\text{ran}\,(A')^\perp. 
$$
In the example above, one has $\text{ran}\,A\subset \ker A$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  $\ker(A)$ is a subset of $X$, while $\ker(A')$ is a subset of $Y'$.

Where you initially seem to go off track is in the equality $\ker (A)=Im(A)^\bot$.  Again, these are subsets of different spaces, hence cannot be equal.

Comment: Do you mean \ker (A)=Im(A)^\bot? Do you agree with the equality $Im(A)=\ker(A')^\bot$?

Comment: I copied exaclty what you posed.  No, but I agree with $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(A)}=\ker(A')_\perp$.